# Is SABR being used in practice for Equity options

Tags: options, stochastic-volatility, banks, sabr

Just to be clear: By "in practice" I mean what the banks and other financial companies do.

**Do financial companies use SABR for pricing equity options?**

Consider a stock with price $t$ being: $S_t$. In SABR model we define the stock dynamics will be:

$$dS_t=S_t^{\beta}\sigma_tdW_t$$
and a process for the volatility. I believe it is not a very good practice to assume no drift for a stock. So that is why I have difficulty understanding how people can use SBAR in practice for Equity while it does make more sense to us it in FX for instance..

Comment: Usually SABR is applied to the forward price of the underlying, so there is no drift.

Comment: Will you be so kind to elaborate?

Comment: Hi. would you clarify what's unclear ?